# Regular expression for substitution

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm working on a way to pass variables into a notification, and to accomplish this, I'm currently going through the message once with the following method:

```
private static function set($var, $content, &$message) {
    $message = str_replace("{{" . $var . "}}", $content, $message);
}
```

This correctly matches; if I have '{{name}}' within message and I run the below method, all instances of '{{name}}' are correctly replaced with 'Johnny Test'. Splendid.

```
self::set('name', 'Johnny Test', $message);
```

---

I'm now looking to expand this to allow for the possibility of a template field not being passed into the notification. That is, if I need 'name' and 'email' for a specific notification but only 'name' gets passed in, I want a default value ('No email address') to be passed in (instead of the notification showing '{{email}}').

To this end, I've concocted the following using [this tool](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html):

```
$returnValue = preg_replace(
    '/\\{\\{.*?\\:\\s*?[\'"](.*?)[\'"]\\s*?\\}\\}/',
    '$1', 
    '{{color : "No color selected"}}'
);
```

However, it doesn't properly match. Instead of `$returnValue` containing 'No color selected', it instead contains the full-on '{{color : "No color selected"}}'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many backslashes. You're working with single quotes, so `\` alone has no special meaning.

Therefore:

```
'/\{\{.*?:\s*[\'"](.*?)[\'"]\s*\}\}/'
```

Should do it.

Comment: Haha, yep! It turned out that the tool I was using was adding that extra backslash (I ended up using writecodeonline to write it out, and the whole thing worked). Thank you for spotting that!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$returnValue = preg_replace(
    '/{{[^:]*:\s*[\'"]([^\'"]*)[\'"]\s*}}/',
    '$1', 
    '{{color : "No color selected"}}'
);
```

Comment: Also a nice solution! It makes the expression more greedy (or rather, less ungreedy).